# how to install xorg-fonts-75dpi properly for xboard?

Tags: xorg, x-windows, dependencies

I am trying to compile xboard but when I tried to run it I got the error

```
xboard: no fonts match pattern -*-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

I googled a bit and found out that xorg-fonts-75dpi or xorg-fonts-100dpi is needed according to this [website](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/5333). However, when I moved xorg-fronts-75dpi files from [here](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/xorg-fonts-75dpi/) to /usr/share/fonts/75dpi xboard still gives the same error. Is there a way I could install from apt-get? If not how should I solve this problem?

btw I am using ubuntu 11.04

**UPDATE**: I just found out that xorg-fonts-75dpi is already installed in /etc/X11/fonts. So according to the link I provided I shouldn't be getting the error. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: It is *not* recommended to install Arch packages to Ubuntu or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In the old X11 font system, the *X11 server* must be told about the font location; it also maintains an internal database of available fonts.

First run **`xset q`** and make sure that "Font Path" lists your X11 font directory (`/etc/X11/fonts`, `/usr/share/fonts/75dpi`, or wherever the hell you moved it later.) If the directory is not listed, use **`xset +fp path`** to add it. (You can use `xset fp default` to reset the default value.)

Afterwards, tell the X11 server to reread its font database with **`xset fp rehash`**.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different bug and Google directed me here.  It's possible that the following may resolve your issue (the error message may have been misleading):

```
./configure --disable-nls && make
./xboard
```

The issue I found is that NLS doesn't work although I have the Helvetica font(s) installed.

Comment: You rock ! Thanks , I tried many things and this worked .